# Unable to build app bundle when spliting application binary on unity. Gradle build error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, build.gradle

i am currently creating an app on unity, i have added ironsource (levelplay) to the app and ever since have been unabel to split application binary and get a successful build.

the errors im getting are:
What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':launcher:checkReleaseDuplicateClasses'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable

it is followed by a lot of lines that say these type of things:

Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimRes found in modules annotation-1.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnimatorRes found in modules annotation-1.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)
Duplicate class androidx.annotation.AnyRes found in modules annotation-1.0 (androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0) and jetified-androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0 (androidx.annotation.annotation-1.2.0.jar)

im really stuck and have tried everything ive found online, any help would be greatly appreciated.

i tried to update all sdks, including ironsource and android, i have reimported ironsource a few times (different versions all) and have tried changing the gradle files.

always getting the same error message